# disnake.py (ошибка) не показывает карточку

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Я хочу чтобы при отправке команды .я у меня показывало карточку

```
@bot.command(aliases = ['я'])
async def card_user(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    img = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 200), '#232529')
    url = str(ctx.author.avatar_url)
    response = requests.get(url, stream = True)
    response = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
    response = response.convert('RGBA')
    response = response.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.paste(response, (15, 15, 115, 115))
    idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    name - ctx.author.name
    tag = ctx.author.discriminator
    headline = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size = 20)
    undertext = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size = 12)
    idraw.text((145, 15), f'{name}#{tag}', font = headline)
    idraw.text((145, 50), f'ID: {ctx.author.id}', font = undertext)
    img.save('user_card.png')
    await ctx.send(file = disnake.File(fp = 'user_card.png'))
```

`У меня выводит ошибку: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'`

Полная ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in command card_user:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Timur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\core.py", line 176, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Love.py", line 55, in card_user
    url = str(ctx.author.avatar_url)
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Timur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\bot_base.py", line 561, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Timur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\core.py", line 930, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Timur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\core.py", line 185, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы руководствуетесь документацией `discord.py`, используя `disnake.py`
У вас ошибка в строке `url = str(ctx.author.avatar_url)`
Используйте `url = str(ctx.author.avatar.url)`

Ссылка на документацию `disnake.py` - https://docs.disnake.dev/en/latest/api.html